# UITextView inside UITableViewCell remove extra paddings

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview, ios-autolayout

I have a `UITextView` inside `UITableViewCell`. I am setting up it's constraint inside

```
if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"noteTextView.text"]) {
        [self setExcludedPaths];

        if (self.noteTextView.text.length > 0) {
            CGSize sizeThatFitsTextView = [self.noteTextView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.noteTextView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT)];
            self.noteTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height;
        } else {
            self.noteTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0.f;
        }
    }
```

But the result is [image]

I have extra pixels at the top and bottom. I want to remove it. What I did:

1) `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in my `UIViewController`

2) In subclass of `UITextView`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:16.f];
    self.textColor = [UIColor noteTextColor];
    self.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    //self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;
    self.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -5, 0, 0);
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
```

if I set `UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, -5, 0, 0);` text moves to top, but extra space at the bottom still exists

Help me out please.

Answer (score 0):

*if I set UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, -5, 0, 0); text moves to top, but extra space at the bottom still exists*

- UIEdgeInsetsMake(CGFloat top, CGFloat left, CGFloat bottom, CGFloat right)

So you can try UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4, 0, -5, 0) instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this for space**

```
yourTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(35, 0, 0);
```

**If you want to remove space between your words**

**TRY THIS**

```
NSString *newString = [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```